# How to output all class in order from left to right from top to bottom in Yolo7?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, yolo, yolov5

I tested with random images and the output like this:

> 3 Cars,4 persons,5 Dogs

how to print all class from left to right from top to bottom:

> car,person,person,person,dog,person,car,dog......

Comment: what have you tried ?  the question needs sufficient code for a minimum reproducable example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I don't know yolov5/yolov7 by maybe it gives you output with coordinates - and then you could sort them by `x, y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoebI.png)

By changing the detect.py file like this, you will get the result you want.

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJoCT.jpg)